# Llamar web desde menu de navegacion

Tags: css, html5, web

Hola uso el siguiente menu de una plantilla que descargue:

```html
<header role="banner" id="fh5co-header">
   <div class="container">
    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="navbar-header">
           <!-- Mobile Toggle Menu Button -->
     <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><i></i></a>
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Voy Palla</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="#" data-nav-section="home"><span>Inicio</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="services"><span>Servicios</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="register"><span>Registrarse</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="contact"><span>Contactenos</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="login.html"><span>Login</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
       </nav>
    </div>
 </header>
```

sin embargo el apartado de login no me funciona, cuando le doy clic no hace nada y el codigo en esencia esta bien ya que se si elimino el id="navbar" funciona el enlace hacia el login pero el menu pierde el disenio y dejan de funcionar las demas opciones del menu aunque no veo nada en particular en el css que me ayude a determinar que agregar para que funcione.

Nota: no puse ninguna ruta ya que el archivo en cuestion el login.html esta afuera al lado del archivo del que sera llamado

Comment: https://github.com/JamtMaster/voypalla ese es el proyecto por si alguien desea descargarlo para entender lo que digo

Comment: solo hay que agregar la clase external antes de la referencia hacia el nuevo elemento en cuestion ya que la configuracion de javascript asi es que lo permite